# How to get id or major or minor from a beacon?

Tags: java, android, beacon, altbeacon

This code detects a beacon but i am not able to get an id or major or minor from it. I tried using beacon.id1() function but it always returns null.
I am trying to implement this since 3 days but i am not able to figure it out i am new to beacon technology. I want to get an id from a beacon.
This code detects a beacon but i am not able to get an id or major or minor from it. I tried using beacon.id1() function but it always returns null.
I am trying to implement this since 3 days but i am not able to figure it out i am new to beacon technology. I want to get an id from a beacon.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);

     beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
           setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));

    beaconManager.bind( this);


    ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglebutton);
    toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                // The toggle is enabled
                Intent eintent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                int intVal=1;
                startActivityForResult(eintent, intVal);
            } else {
                // The toggle is disabled
                BluetoothAdapter bAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                bAdapter.disable();
            }
        }
    });


}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    beaconManager.unbind((BeaconConsumer) this);
}

public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    beaconManager.removeAllMonitorNotifiers();
    beaconManager.addMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {


        @Override
        public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "Beacon Found";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
            Log.d(TAG, "I just saw a beacon for the first time!");

            a=beacon.getServiceUuid();

            Toast toastt = Toast.makeText(context,"" + a, duration);
            toastt.show();
        }

        @Override
        public void didExitRegion(org.altbeacon.beacon.Region region) {
            Log.i(TAG, "I no longer see a beacon");
        }

        @Override
        public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int i, org.altbeacon.beacon.Region region) {
            //Log.i(TAG, "I have just switched from seeing/not seeing beacons: "+state);
        }

    });

   try {
        beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(new org.altbeacon.beacon.Region("MY_UUID", null, null, null));
        //beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new org.altbeacon.beacon.Region("myranging", null, null, null));
    }
    catch (RemoteException e) {    }
}

@Override
public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understand that using monitoring APIs, you only get a callback when *any* beacon (one or more) is in the vicinity that matches your `Region` definition.  The code shown defines a region setting all the identifiers to null.  This is what is known as a wildcard Region because it matches any beacon.

When you get a callback to `didEnterRegion` it passes a copy of the same `Region` definition you used to start monitoring.  And because you set all the identifiers to null (a wildcard definition) that is what you get when you inspect the identifiers of the `Region` object passed to that method.  These APIs are designed to tell you when any one of a *group* of beacons has appeared.

If you want to know the specific identifiers of the beacons that are visible, you simply need to use ranging APIs.  Instead of:

```
beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(new org.altbeacon.beacon.Region("MY_UUID", null, null, null));
```

Call:

```
 beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new org.altbeacon.beacon.Region("MY_UUID", null, null, null));
```

And then set your callback notifier like this:

```
beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
    @Override
    public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Region region, Collection<Beacon> beacons) {
        for (Beacon beacon: beacons} {
          Log.d(TAG, "I see a beacon with ID1 of: "+beacon.getID1());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much this worked and helped me solve the issue.